# How do I configure MySQL command line client key bindings?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, keys, key-bindings

I often use the mysql command-line client on an Ubuntu box.  It works fine, except that the key bindings are wrong.  Specifically, pressing "Home", "End", or "Delete" makes it output a ~ (tilde) character, and beep.

I've determined that Home/End can be done by pressing Control+A and Control+E respectively, as on the Mac terminal.  I'm on a Windows box, using PuTTY to talk to Ubuntu, but the home/end/delete keys work fine on the regular command line.  I'm pretty sure it's an issue specific to the mysql client.

I checked the man file but didn't find anything useful.  Is there any way to bind the Home/End/Delete keys to their actual functions? Maybe a config file in my home directory or something?

Every time I move back a few spaces to edit a query and press delete, I just wind up having to go forward again so I can use the Backspace key to delete not only the incorrect query but also the ~ that the delete key puts in.

It's driving me slowly but surely to madness.  Madness, I tell you, **MADNESS!**

Comment: Not really suitable for ServerFault (more a SuperUser or Unix & Linux question) but I'll answer anyway.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure where to put this, but ServerFault seemed reasonable since a pretty high proportion of server admins are familiar with the software involved. Thanks for answering anyway; in future I'll save ServerFault for truly server-ish things like problems configuring a load balancer or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I noticed that my home server did not have the problem, and comparing the work and home servers let me finally nail it down.

It's a bug Ubuntu introduced in version 9.10, which is what my work server is running.  Specifically, the version of /usr/bin/mysql in Ubuntu 9.10 uses the EditLine wrapper instead of the readline wrapper:

```
wmartin@work:~$ mysql --version && md5sum /usr/bin/mysql && lsb_release -a

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.37, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using EditLine wrapper

e23604381e64ac805fdbb8b334ce4d17  /usr/bin/mysql

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:        9.10
Codename:       karmic
```

Compare to the more recent release on my home server:

```
wmartin@home:~$ mysql --version && md5sum /usr/bin/mysql && lsb_release -a

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1

4274c43798239142576e77c022d35bd1  /usr/bin/mysql

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
```

The 10.04 (and presumably later) versions work just fine -- mysql honors the home/end/delete keys using Putty's default settings.

So the solution is either to upgrade the server to 10.04 or later, or to use the command line utility `rlwrap` to wrap the mysql client in a readline environment, as described in the blog post [restoring readline capabilities of Ubuntu's 9.10 (Karmic Koala) MySQL Client](http://blog.melimato.com/restoring-readline-capabilities-of-ubuntus-9-10-karmic-koala-mysql-client/).

Sadly, the `rlwrap` approach has the nasty side effect of making your password visible when you type it in instead of suppressing its output. So I think I'll take the upgrade route.

Comment: Well done for tracking it down - using the Ubuntu LTS releases is much preferred to "whatever is the latest release" for servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem is your PuTTY settings - in the connection window, under "Terminal", "Keyboard" - change options for "The Home and End keys" to `rxvt`. Not perfect (End won't work still) but you'll get Home and Delete.

IMO the real solution is to use a proper terminal & proper SSH; [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) is reasonably good for a terminal, and MSYS or Cygwin can give you SSH (msysgit has it included).

**Edit**:

Sounds like you've found the bug in MySQL CLI.

Comment: Actually, I take it back.  That didn't fix it.  In BASH, I get Home and Delete but not End (which is worse -- all three worked in BASH before).  In the MySQL client, Home works, but Delete and End still do tildes.  Doing more investigation ...

Comment: @Will fair enough.